# Recursive function VS If-Else

Tags: c, recursion

I'm trying to make a recursive function in C who returns the length of a string.

If i make it with If-Else block it works as expected :

```
int myFunctionCountRecursive(const char* s, int i) {

    if (s[i] != '\0') {
        i++;
        myFunctionCountRecursive(s, i);
    }
    else
        return i;
}
```

But when i try to make it with a ternary i see that the `i` variable increment as well but after the return the function run a second time and decrement `i` ?

```
int myFunctionCountRecursive(const char* s, int i) {

    (s[i] != '\0') ? myFunctionCountRecursive(s, ++i) : 0;
    return i;
}
```

In order to get the result expected i have to write :

```
int myFunctionCountRecursive(const char* s, int i) {

    return (s[i] != '\0') ? myFunctionCountRecursive(s, ++i) : i;
}
```

Does anyone can explain why this behavior happend ?
Thanks

Comment: Does the first code need to **return** `myFunctionCountRecursive(s, i);` ? Add the `return` because not all control paths return a value.

Comment: Your second code is always returning the `i`, while the first only when `(s[i] != '\0')` this false.

Comment: Assuming that something outside of the code you have shown is accessing the value returned from `myFunctionCountRecursive`, the first two snippets have Undefined Behavior.

Comment: *If i make it with If-Else block it works as expected :*  No it doesn't.  It just **appears** to work.  If `s[i]` is not equal to `'\0'`, the code in the first example doesn't properly return any value.

Comment: You should [always] compile with `-Wall -O2`. The first two examples will return warnings.

Comment: The '\0' will always appear in the end of a char[], isnt'it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your second code is essentially this

```
int myFunctionCountRecursive(const char* s, int i) {

    if (s[i] != '\0')
        myFunctionCountRecursive(s, ++i);
    else
        0;

    return i;
}
```

which is clearly different then the first one. `return i` will always execute eventually. While with the first and third one only when `(s[i] != '\0')` this `false`.